# How the way to respond to "You want something?"

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I got a friend who wanted to go to the store. Before leaving he told us like this: 
A: **"guys, I'm going to grab some drink. You guys want something?**
then, one of my friend made a response with: 
B: **"Yes, can you get me Coca Cola and chips?"**

So, is my friend's response correct and natural ? or are there some ways to response that kinda question that sound more natural?

Thanks

Comment: In British English, it would be " B: "Yes, can you get me Coca Cola and **some** chips?" -- "Chips" has different meanings in AE and BE. I will assume that the conversation is in American English - the response is informal and idiomatic (although I personally hate "guys".)

Comment: @Greybeard See [Nobody cares how YOU pronounce it](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6603/73636).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly. In my country that's stilted, but it might be acceptable in yours. I would say

> Yeah, can you get me a coke and some chips?

I'm a little concerned about the lack of quantity for "Coca Cola." Say

> Yes, can you get me a Coca Cola and chips?

or

> Yes, can you get me some Coca Cola and chips?